# SQL WHERE clause to pull records based on dates that re 91-97 days away from current date

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I don't have a lot of experience with SQL, but I'm needing to figure out how to use the WHERE clause to pull in dates 91-97 days away (in the future) from the current date and from a specific date.

What's happened is every Monday, this query is ran but something happened with our system to prevent it from being ran.  So I'm wanting it to run from the start of this week (3/11), but I'd also like the code for doing it on the current date as well.

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: It's Oracle11g.

Answer (score 0):

The standard SQL for this is:

```
where datecol >= current_date + interval '91 day' and
      datecol < current_date + interval '98 day'
```

Some databases support this particular syntax.  All databases have this functionality in some form.

In Oracle, I would express this as:

```
where datecol >= trunc(sysdate) + interval '91' day and
      datecol < trunc(sysdate) + interval '98' day
```

Comment: Actually standard SQL would be `interval '91' day`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I thought the standards supported things like interval '91 day 2 hour'.

Comment: I've added the database.  Oracle11g

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I think that would be something like `interval '92 5' day to hour` - but Oracle definitely does not allow `interval '91 day'`)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server and i get you right:

```
SELECT DATEADD(Day,a,Convert(date, getdate()))
  FROM (VALUES (91),(92),(93),(94),(95),(96),(97)) AS X(a)
```

Returns you a list of all dates between 91 and 97 days in future of the current date.